# How do I include a header from a separate directory in addition to including functions from a file from a different directory?

Tags: c, header-files

I have 3 directories, `src`, `lib`, and `include`. In `include` I have header file `header3.h`. Its code is as follows:

```
// header3.h
extern void change(int *a);
```

In `lib` I have file `change4.c`, which contains:

```
// change4.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header3.h"

void change(int *a){
    int y=100;
    a=y;
}
```

In `src` I have file `manipulate5.c`, which contains:

```
// manipulate5.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header3.h"

int main(void){
     int x=10;
     printf("x is %d\n", x );
     change(&x);
     printf("x is now %d\n", x );
}
```

When I attempt to compile `manipulate5.c` with following command:

```
gcc -I ../include manipulate5.c`
```

when in directory `src`, I get the following error:

```
In function main:
manipulate5.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to change
```

So how do I get `manipulate5.c` to properly work?

Comment: Try `gcc -I ../include change4.c manipulate5.c`. You need to compile and link the function implementation as well.

Comment: That did not work. Produces error that change4.c does not exist. So is the linking the solution? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Does not exist? Is it in the same directory as manipulate5.c?

Comment: No, and that is my question. Each file is in its own directory, and I am supposed to keep it that way.

Comment: Then either give it a path to it, or compile each file into `.o` by itself and then link them.

Comment: I do not remember the syntax for compiling into .o, is it gcc -I ../include manipulate5.o manipulate5.c?

Comment: Refer to the docs. If you give `gcc` the `-c` option, it will only perform compilation without linking.

Comment: How do I link .o files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)